# How do I convert one date format into another date format in Java?

Tags: java, date, format, data-conversion

I have a variable `myDateString` that contains a date String that looks like this:

> 2008-06-20 15:30:11.656

I'm trying to figure out how to transform this from its current format to the following:

> June 20, 2008

I'm trying to use SimpleDateFormat to achieve this, but I can't quite seem to figure it out.  So far I have

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
Date myDate = sdf.parse(myDateString);
System.out.println(????);
```

My original idea was to use the Date methods such as getDay(), getMonth(), etc. and just concatenate all of these together into the string I want.  Unfortunately, as far as I can see, there is no method to print out the month name, only the month number.

How do I convert my date string to the desired date output in Java?

Comment: you need two `SimpleDateFormat`. One to go from `String` -> `Date` with the input format and one to go from `Date` -> `String` with the outputformat

Comment: Is there a good reason to work with `Date` objects? That class is obsolete and badly written, and it's better to use `java.time` in Java 8, or Joda-Time in earlier versions of Java.

Comment: @RealSkeptic nope.  I was just Googling around and I found it.  I can give java.time a look for sure!

Comment: @KevinEsche could you possibly elaborate more?  I'm still not able to figure it out.  I do what I did above, but then after the myDate gets created, I create another new simpledateformat of format ("MMMM d, yyyy"), and then I do a parse of myDate.toString() and convert that result to a string.  What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the Date object (notice @RealSkeptic´s comment) you would need to do it like this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    Date d = f.parse("2008-06-20 15:30:11.656"); // Format String to a dateobject with the format provided by the String.
    SimpleDateFormat f2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy"); // MMMM for full month name
    System.out.println(f2.format(d)); // Use the second format to create the desired format as String with d as input.
}
```